# creating a simple event in apache-kafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am trying to follow the intro example to apache-kafka and i am having a hard time creating a simple event.

when i run the following command inside the project nothing happens:

```
node producer.js getting-started.properties
```

this use to work before, but now its not working.

this is the step and guide that I am following: https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/nodejs/#produce-events

any idea what might be wrong?

[image: terminal pic]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `getting-started.properties` file doesn't exist.

Creating this is documented in an earlier step: https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/nodejs/#configuration